# RandomForestClassifier of only 50% for sentiment analysis of good and bad movie reviews

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest

I am trying to train a RandomForestClassifier to predict whether a review is good (1) or bad (0) based upon the word count.

My training data named `all_train_set` looks like this:

```
                                                 Reviews  Labels
0      For fans of Chris Farley, this is probably his...       1
1      Fantastic, Madonna at her finest, the film is ...       1
2      From a perspective that it is possible to make...       1
3      What is often neglected about Harold Lloyd is ...       1
4      You'll either love or hate movies such as this...       1
                                              ...     ...
14995  This is perhaps the worst movie I have ever se...       0
14996  I was so looking forward to seeing this film t...       0
14997  It pains me to see an awesome movie turn into ...       0
14998  "Grande Ecole" is not an artful exploration of...       0
14999  I felt like I was watching an example of how n...       0
```

The test dataset looks exactly the same format. The code used to train my algorithm is as such:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
import nltk
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report, accuracy_score
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier as rfc

stopwords=set(nltk.corpus.stopwords.words('english'))



tfidfconverter = TfidfVectorizer(max_features=1500, min_df=5, stop_words=stopwords)
X = tfidfconverter.fit_transform(all_train_set['Reviews']).toarray()
X_train = X
y_train = all_train_set['Labels']

classifier = rfc(n_estimators=1000, random_state=0)
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)

tfidfconverter = TfidfVectorizer(max_features=1500, min_df=5, stop_words=stopwords)
X = tfidfconverter.fit_transform(all_test_set['Reviews']).toarray()
X_test = X
y_test = all_test_set['Labels']

#predicting on the test set and printing results
y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)

print(classification_report(y_test,y_pred))
print(accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred))
```

My overall accuracy is 0.5 which seems extremely poor. After this I tried a grid search to obtain the best parameters but the overall accuracy was again exactly 0.5. The results look like this:

```
              precision    recall  f1-score   support
           0       0.50      0.70      0.58      2482
           1       0.50      0.30      0.37      2482
    accuracy                           0.50      4964
   macro avg       0.50      0.50      0.48      4964
weighted avg       0.50      0.50      0.48      4964

0.5
```

If anyone can explain whether this is a training error or if it is just a poor result. If the latter is there anyway I can know how to improve it?

I am new to machine learning and so apologies if anything is not clear, I am happy to clarify/make edits/ take advice on how to improve my question.

Many thanks

Comment: Looking at your code, it seems that training data is also testing data. Keep them different else the purpose of ML is defeated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a few things like:

1. You shouldn't `fit_transform` on test set, just `transform`. So don't reinitialise `tfidfconverter`.
2. You could try **cleaning** your data, **hyperparameter tuning**, **different algorithms**. On text data, algorithms like `LinearSVC` work great. But you can experiment on that.
3. Create **new features** from text. Look up examples from github or Kaggle kernels for that.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, as you are defining:

```
X_train = X
X_test = X
```

This is wrong, a supervised learning algorithm (classification problem) always has a train/test-split. So you train your algorithm and then test it with unseen data!
The scikit function you can find [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html).

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)
```

As Shwetea already mentioned, you also should not `fit_transform`your test data, you only should use `transform` otherwise again using information of your test set which should not be know for the algorithm.

To get an idea how good your score is you can use a [Dummy Classifier](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.dummy.DummyClassifier.html), this will alwayse e.g. predict the major class, so for example if your label 1 has only 10% of your labels, the dummy score will be 90% (as it always will predict 0). If your dummy score is close or above 0.5 you have a really bad algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that there is a very weak relationship (or no relationship) between the features you are using to train your model and the labels. As a result, your model has a very poor performance. This is very common in machine learning experiments.

I suggest you first focus on generating a larger set of features (borrow from academic papers or other similar projects). Then you can use feature selection methods to select the best features.

You can check out the following:

https://medium.com/@MarynaL/analyzing-movie-review-data-with-natural-language-processing-7c5cba6ed922

https://github.com/deepakchaudhari705/Sentimental-Analysis-on-a-Movie-Data-/blob/master/sentiment-checkpoint.ipynb